# How to load complex contents from file into Python program specifically?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with the input for a programming assignment:

> People in a town go shopping many times on a weekly basis. The town mayor wants to keep track of how many items a person buys every time they go shopping. He is only monitoring three houses. In each house, there are five members of the family. The data for each family should be kept separately.
>   Code to solve this program.

Now, the file contents have to be loaded and saved to a file.
I have planned for the input (for the first task) to look like the following in the file itself and also I would like it to appear as such when loaded into the program:

```
[['James',0],['Katherine',0],['Jacob',0],['Michael',0],['Cyndia',0]]
```

However, the code I currently have, which goes:

```
Class11A = []

def Class(FileLabel,FileName,ReadLabel,Class):

    FileLabel = open(FileName,mode = 'r+')
    ReadLabel = FileLabel.read()
    for line in ReadLabel:
        Class.append(line)

Class('Class11A','Class 11A.txt','Class11ATempList',Class11A)
print (Class11A)
```

Yet, the code loads the contents like such:

```
['[', '[', "'", 'J', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's', "'", ',', '0', ']', ',', '[', "'", 'K', 'a', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'e', "'", ',', '0', ']', '[', "'", 'J', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'b', "'", ',', '0', ']', '[', "'", 'M', 'i', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'e', 'l', "'", ',', '0', ']', '[', "'", 'C', 'y', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a', "'", ',', '0', ']', ']']
```

How do I solve this?

Note: The same file structure will be used to load the data for the other two families.

Comment: Can you please explain what your function is supposed to do?  The name is not descriptive and is *very* similar to a Python reserved word.  You use the *same* name for one of your parameters.  You never use the third parameter's value.  Your choice of data representation is curious: the default print representation of a Python variable is generally not particularly useful for storing the values.

Comment: this is not a good way to store your names,visits ....

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that **read()** reads an entire file.  ReadLabel is now the entire file content as a string.  Your naming seems to think that it's still in line-by-line form, but it's just a string.  Thus, **line** is merely a series of characters, which you individually append to a list.

One possible repair is to use the eval() operation to turn the string into a list:

```
family_list = eval(ReadLabel)
```

This gives you the list of five lists.  TO illustrate:

```
target = "[['James',0],['Katherine',0],['Jacob',0],['Michael',0],['Cyndia',0]]"
target_list = eval(target)
print len(target_list), target_list[1]
```

This gives the output

```
5 ['Katherine', 0]
```

I hope this gets you unstuck.  You still have many minor decisions to make or repair.

Comment: How do I input from a file though @Prune ?

Comment: Use **readline** instead of **read**.  See section [7.2](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for basic input and output.

Comment: How should the contents in the file be stored? Sorry, I have not the full grasp of this. @Prune

Comment: With code :                                                          
    ReadLabel = FileLabel.readline()
    Class = eval(ReadLabel)                                                                                Output is: File "<string>", line 1
    '[['James',0],['Katherine',0],['Jacob',0],['Michael',0],['Cyndia',0]]'
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax        @Prune

Comment: That depends on your program design -- which you haven't yet explained.  I'm not going to lead you through the process step-by-step; StackOverflow is not a place for tutorial help.  When you have a specific question about code you've written, post a new question.  You're using the correct coding process: write a few lines, debug those, and then move ahead.

Comment: For that posting, please supply basic debugging info: print out the values of critical variables just before the point of failure.  I can't even help with the error message; there isn't enough context.  It looks like you fed readline a file name instead of a file handle, but it's hard to tell from this.  Successive comments on this site are not an effective debugging method.

Comment: Can you have this question permanently deleted since it has been downvoted a lot so I do not feel as if it is useful for the community?